# Return a query with datetime existing in both tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return a table which joins data from an ads table and a website traffic table, both with hour level data. However, a timestamp that exists for a particular day in the ads table may not exist in the website table. For example, timestamp "2017-09-27 20:00:00+00" exists in the website traffic table but not in the ads table, and vice versa.

I am using using a query which selects the ads table timestamp, but using a left join. A full outer join does not seem to solve this issue, most likely due to selecting the ads timestamp and not the website traffic timestamp.

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to return the timestamp of both tables in one column?

Much appreciated.

The query currently being used is as follows:

```
SELECT
    ads.phase AS "phase",
    ads.datetime_utc AS "datetime",
    lower(array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(ads.placement, '_'))[1:9], '_')) AS "delim_dims",
    a.name AS " name",
    ads.device AS "device",
    sum(ads.impressions) AS "impressions",
    sum(ads.clicks) AS "clicks",
    sum(ads.spend) AS "spend",
    web.sessions AS "sessions",
    web.bounces AS "bounces"
FROM
    ads_data AS ads
INNER JOIN
    lookup.names_lookup AS a ON
    ads.lookup_code = a.lookup_code
LEFT JOIN -- tested with FULL OUTER JOIN, returns same results
    web.website_traffic AS web ON
    ads.datetime_utc = web.datetime_est
    AND
    a.lookup_code = web.lookup_code
    AND
    ads.device = web.device
GROUP BY
    ads.phase,
    datetime,
    delim_dims,
    a.audience_name,
    web.sessions,
    web.bounces,
    device
HAVING
    sum(ads.spend) > 0
```

Comment: `coalesce(first_ts,next_ts,default_ts)` would help

Comment: Thanks for the coalesce suggestion. I tested it out, but it still didn't return the records I was looking for.

Comment: please be constructive. exact statement. exact result. exact expectations.

Comment: Will you please do some exercise to provide sample data and desired output ?

Comment: I'm away for now, but I am almost certain it has to do with the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your wording because your question title asks for "a datetime existing in both tables" which suggests you only want rows with a matching datetime in both ads_data and web.website_traffic. But then you want to use a LEFT JOIN or a FULL OUTER JOIN for some reason, which makes me think you want rows with a datetime in one of the columns. The way I interpret this is that you want a column with the datetime from either table; if it happens to be row with matching timestamps, great; if there's only a timestamp in one or the other table, return that.

It looks like your problem is you're doing an INNER JOIN between lookup.names_lookup (a) and ads_data. TheN when you join to web.website_traffic, one of your join conditions is a.lookup_code = web.lookup_code. That essentially converts your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN, so you're only getting results for data in ads_data, and none of the cases with a row in web.website_traffic but not ads_data.

Instead, I would start with a subquery (CTE) that is a full outer join of ads_data with web.website_traffic to get all non-matching rows + all matching rows together, then inner join that with lookup.names_lookup.

A few more issues I noticed:

1. The ads_data datetime column's name refrs to UTC time, whereas the web.website_traffic column refers to EST time.
2. I think it's weird that you're grouping by sessions and bounces, since those are numeric: I'd probably do a min on those instead.
3. You reference "delim_dims" in the GROUP BY, but since you calculated that in the SELECT clause, you have to repeat the calculation in the GROUP BY (the SELECT clause is evaluated last)

Here's some SQL to try (ignoring that potential UTC vs EST issue):

```
WITH alldata AS (
    SELECT
        ads.phase,
        COALESCE(ads.datetime_utc, web.datetime_est) AS "datetime",
        COALESCE(ads.lookup_code, web.lookup_code) AS "lookup_code",
        COALESCE(ads.device, web.device) AS "device",
        ads.placement,
        ads.impressions,
        ads.clicks,
        ads.spend,
        web.sessions,
        web.bounces
    FROM
        ads_data AS ads FULL OUTER JOIN web.website_traffic AS web ON
            ads.datetime_utc = web.datetime_est AND
            ads.lookup_code = web.lookup_code AND
            ads.device = web.device
)
SELECT
    alldata.phase AS "phase",
    alldata.datetime AS "datetime",
    lower(array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(alldata.placement, '_'))[1:9], '_')) AS "delim_dims",
    a.name AS "name",
    alldata.device AS "device",
    sum(alldata.impressions) AS "impressions",
    sum(alldata.clicks) AS "clicks",
    sum(alldata.spend) AS "spend",
    min(alldata.sessions) AS "sessions",
    min(alldata.bounces) AS "bounces"
FROM
    alldata INNER JOIN lookup.names_lookup AS a ON 
        alldata.lookup_code = a.lookup_code
GROUP BY
    alldata.phase,
    alldata.datetime,
    lower(array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(alldata.placement, '_'))[1:9], '_')),
    a.audience_name,
    alldata.device
HAVING
    sum(ads.spend) > 0
```